# check if record with same mobile number exists in two different objects

Tags: trigger

I am learning salesforce. I need to check if  record with same mobile number exists in two different objects. So how can i achieve this. Kindly help, efforts are appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything for yourself yet? Can you be more specific about where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOSL Query to find the record
Example : Find 'MobileNo' in all fields returning Obj1 ,Obj2

Let me know if it works!